# Selected Tab is not highlighted in the Navbar in reactjs bootstrap?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, navbar, react-bootstrap, onselect

I am able to simply highlight the tab selected from the NavBar. I had used the Navbar Component of React-bootstrap and used the state to change the bgColor and textColor of the selected tab. But instead of the selected tab, it is highlighting all the tabs? Any corrections?

What I want is to highlight the clicked tab only? It should remain highlighted all the time when we are on that page (like tab component or nav-pills).

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Navbar, Container, Nav } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { LogOut } from './LogOut';

const NavbarComponent = () => {
  const [bgcolor, setBgcolor] = useState('black');
  const [textcolor, setTextcolor] = useState('white');

  function handleHighlightTab() {
    setBgcolor('white');
    setTextcolor('black');
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Navbar bg="dark" variant="dark" fixed="top" className="nav-pills">
        <Container>
          <Navbar.Brand href="/">Verticals</Navbar.Brand>
          <Nav className="me-auto">
            <Nav.Link
              href="/grocery"
              onSelect={handleHighlightTab}
              style={{ backgroundColor: bgcolor, color: textcolor }}
            >
              Grocery
            </Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link
              href="/fashion"
              onSelect={handleHighlightTab}
              style={{ backgroundColor: bgcolor, color: textcolor }}
            >
              Fashion
            </Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link
              href="/footwear"
              onSelect={handleHighlightTab}
              style={{ backgroundColor: bgcolor, color: textcolor }}
            >
              Footwear
            </Nav.Link>
          </Nav>
        </Container>
      </Navbar>;
    </>
  );
};

export default NavbarComponent;
```

Comment: `<Nav.Link />` component will have an `active` className when selected, so you won't need to handle this yourself using `useState`. Alternatively, you can control the `active` state using the [active](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navs/#nav-link-props) prop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command in CSS file for me it worked out

```css
.nav-pills .nav-link.active
```

Comment: **Explanation**:
If you inspect elements, you will see that `Nav.Link` probably has a class named `nav-link`. And when it is active, `active` class will be added to its class list.

Here is the [source code of `Nav.Link`](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/blob/master/src/NavLink.tsx#L82). Please pay attention that you may change `nav-link` class, using `bsPrefix`.

Comment: You should probably use `.nav-pills .nav-link.active` as the selector. Note the space between `.nav-pills` and `.nav-link`. `Nav.Link` is a child of `Navbar`.